# Adding custom css-files to theme (page.xml) - custom css-files for single storeviews

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, css, custom

**Question #1:**
For some reason, I can't seem to get my custom CSS file to be implemented into the theme. I've basically done this with the page.xml:

Before:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 9</if></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-iefont.css</name><params/><if>gt IE 6</if></action>
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/widgets.css</stylesheet></action>
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/print.css</stylesheet><params>media="print"</params></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ds-sleight.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
```

After: (added inbetween)

```
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/widgets.css</stylesheet></action>
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/print.css</stylesheet><params>media="print"</params></action>

<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/hafner.css</stylesheet><params>media="screen"</params></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/hafner.css</name></action>

<action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ds-sleight.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
```

Am I missing something?

The code is in `<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">`

**Question #2: (the relevant one)**

How to add custom CSS-files for single storeviews?

Answered by Jonathan Hussey (see below)

**edit02:** it seems I don't get it quite just yet.

```
</default>

<!-- CUSTOM -->
<STORE_hafner_de>
    <reference name="header">
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/hafner.css</stylesheet><params>media="screen"</params></action>
    </reference>
</STORE_hafner_de>
```

that `</default>` is just to show that `<default>` is closed

Comment: I've changed my question, thank you for the help with the previous one though.

Comment: Please don't change the question if it has been answered. Instead, post a new question while linking to this question as the reference to follow-up.

Comment: I've realized and accepted that already, however the first question was highly irrelevant. It was essentially me being stupid.

Comment: @AndrewT. thanks to your edit however I can't repost my second question, because it has been answered in this thread, the first one, however, has only been commented.
Which means the current answer is related to question #2, not the first one, so your re-edit is not really on-topic.

Comment: Okay, I understand :) Feel free to improve this question by editing it, but make sure to make the answer still legit. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `STORE` layout handle:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <STORE_en>
        <reference name="content">
            ...
        </reference>
    </STORE_en>
</layout>
```

Where `en` is the code of the store in question.  This will add the layout changes to all pages for that store in the same way as the `<default>` layout handle does for all pages of all stores.  By default there is no way to use the `STORE` layout handle and only have layout changes for certain pages in that store.

FYI, next time just create a new question rather than completely changing an existing one so the comments don't make any sense - SE is a resource for people to refer to in the future as well as a way for you to have your questions answered.

Comment: I know, sorry about that, but I felt the question was not as useful as I first expected it to be, since the cache was essentially the only problem. I guess I'm a bit tired today.

Comment: so I basically use:
`<STORE_storename><block>...</block></STORE_storename>` ?

Comment: The `STORE` layout handle is used just like any other layout handle such as `default` or `catalog_product_view`.

Comment: which means I have to add this code either at the top or the bottom of the XML-file?
`<STORE_hafner_de>
   <reference name="content">
      <action method=".."....</action>
   </reference>
</STORE_hafner_de>` after <default> closes?

Comment: Yes you still have to reference, or create a block as normal within the handle.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I was trying to modify some color of a premium theme and saving it doesn't take any effect.

I tried to put into `local.xml` and `page.xml` without any success. Finally I figured out that this theme uses **LESS**. So I looked for LESS folders and edited `my-theme.less` (also `my-theme.css` into css folder). 
Then I refreshed cache and the change took effect.

This is how my parent's tree theme looks like:

```
skin
|
| ---- mypackage
    |
    |---- default
        |
        |---- less
        |   |
        |   |---- my-theme.less
        |---- css
        |   |
        |   |---- my-theme.css
        |---- images
        |
        |---- js
```

Hope this works for you.